# Explaining why this algorithm is n^2

Tags: algorithm, time, runtime, time-complexity

I'm having some trouble argumenting for the runtime of this code. I know the code runs at O(n^2), but I've been told to explain why it does. I figured I need to do some calculations on it but I'm stuck.
The algorithm (Pseudo code) I need to figure out is.

```
    count = 0                        1
    for i = 0 to n-2                 n
        for j = 1 to n               n^2
            if A[j]<A[i]             1
                count = count + 1    1
```

I've written what I think is the runtime of each line as well. However, I don't know if this is correct.

Comment: What confuses you?

Comment: I've been told to explain why the algorithm runs at O(n^2). So what confuses me is how I'm suppose to write it, how do I go from what I have to the answer O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

outer for loop traverses from 0 to n-2

Removing constants in outer loop, we could say it will loop for n times.
for each number in the range [0..n-2] in outer loop, inner loop iterates from [1..n]

```
if i=0, inner loop runs from 1 to n,
if i=1, inner loop runs from 1 to n,
.
.
.
till  i=n-2, inner loop runs from 1 to n,
```

so time complexity would be (outer loop * inner loop) = `O(n*n)`  which is `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

The outer `for` loop iterates exactly `n-1 = O(n)` times. On each iteration of the outer `for` loop, the inner `for` loop iterates exactly `n = O(n)` times, so overall it iterates `O(n^2)` times. The work done inside the inner loop is constant time, `O(1)`. Therefore, the overall time complexity is `O(n^2)`, since we repeated `O(1)` amount of work `O(n^2)` times.